# Add Object in ListView

Tags: vb.net, listview

I have an Object and I want to have a List of that Object in a Control List such as ListView.

When I DoubleClick that Object in ListView, I would like to get that specific Object and use it on another Form. But I can't retrieve that Object when I use `listview1.SelectedItems`.

How can I achieve that ?

Comment: If you're setting the `View` to `Details` then you probably shouldn't be using a `ListView` in the first place. If you have a list of objects in the first place then you probably ought to be binding that to a `BindingSource` and binding that to a `DataGridView`. Each row in the grid has a `DataBoundItem` property that will automatically expose the item from the underlying list.

Comment: By the way, the Visual Studio tag specifically states that it is for issues using the IDE, not for problems with code written in VS. Only use relevant tags.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A `ListView` contains `ListViewItem` objects. That's it, that's all. When the user selects an item, they are selecting a `ListViewItem` object. If you want to then access some other object that is related to that item, it's up to you to create an explicit relationship of some kind between them. A common means to do that is to assign those original objects to the `Tag` property of the corresponding `ListViewItem`, e.g.

```vb
For each something As Thing In myThings
    Dim item As New ListViewItem

    item.Tag = something

    '...

    myListView.Items.Add(item)
Next
```

You can then get those objects back from the `Tag` properties of the selected items, e.g.

```vb
For Each item As ListViewItem In myListView.SelectedItems
    Dim something = DirectCast(item.Tag, Thing)

    '...
Next
```

Comment: Does the `Tag` property can access to the specific Object in a collection ?

Comment: Edit:

I first add the Object in a collection then I add to ListView.

Because, what I understand about your code is, it's assigned a `Tag` to each Object and you add that Item in the ListView . But the `Tag` property assign automatically a `Tag` ?

Comment: The `Tag` property is just a general-purpose holder where you can put any object you like that is associated with the `ListViewItem`. You said that you want to be able to access a specific object when you select an item and I told you how to do. Do it. Put that object in the item's `Tag` property. It's not rocket surgery.

Comment: Yes I made it worked.
I thought that I have to put my own `Tag` that's why I was confused.
Thanks